# Экспорт TableView в excel

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx, excel

Я создал таблицу (TableView), которая заполняется данными из БД. Теперь хочу вывести Эту таблицу в excel,
Но вы ходит вот такая вот шляпа[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код для заполнения таблицы

```
Connection table;
ResultSet rs = null;
table = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
String PostSQL = "SELECT * from " + Constant.TABLE_OF_ORGANIZATION;
try{
    rs =  table.createStatement().executeQuery(PostSQL);
    for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
        final int j = i;
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(col);
        System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");
    }

    while(rs.next()){
        //Iterate Row
        ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //Iterate Column
            row.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
        data.add(row);
    }
    tableView.setItems(data);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
}
```

В excel я выводил вот так

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");

HSSFRow row = null;

for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < tableView.getColumns().size(); j++) {
        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(tableView.getColumns().get(j).toString());
    }
}

FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
try {
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    workbook.write(fileOut);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    fileOut.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Вот так выглядит таблица[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во внутреннем цикле нужно брать данные не из колонок (колонки сами не содержат данных), а из строки из `tableView.getItems()` по индексу `i`.

Я предполагаю, что тип строки таблицы у вас `ObservableList<String>` (судя по коду заполнения таблицы), можно просто циклом проходить по этому списку:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < tableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
    row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
    ObservableList<String> currentRow = tableView.getItems().get(i)
    for (int j = 0; j < currentRow.size(); j++) {
        row.createCell(j).setCellValue(currentRow.get(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо